# Force OpenLayers v3 map to display in English

Tags: openlayers-3

Is there a way to display the Openlayers map just in English? It currently displays by default in all languages depending on the user's locale.

Comment: Are you using a BingMaps source? If so, you'll need to set the `culture` config option to your desired culture.

Comment: No, I am using the openlayers map

Comment: There is no openlayers map. Can you share your code, or at least describe what type of layer and source you are using?